# Bluetooth virtual sniffer for windows

Tags: bluetooth

I want to sniff bluetooth packets using btvs.exe and collect it to pcap file. If you just open btvs.exe, then such a window will open, besides, if there is wireshark, then this traffic will open in it. However, I want to save the traffic automatically using at most a few commands, for example using python os
[opening btvs.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDU9P.png)

I saw microsoft resourse - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/testing-btp-tools-btvs)
but there is no such parameter

Answer (score 0):

In modern computers, most Bluetooth adapters are connected to the computer's USB subsystem. An optional component of Wireshark is USBPcap, which is supplied with `USBPcapCMD.exe`. The `-o` option allows you to save the traffic to a pcap file.

```
C:\Program Files\USBPcap>Usage: USBPcapCMD.exe [options]
  -h, -?, --help
    Prints this help.
  -d <device>, --device <device>
    USBPcap control device to open. Example: -d \\.\USBPcap1.
  -o <file>, --output <file>
    Output .pcap file name.
  -s <len>, --snaplen <len>
    Sets snapshot length.
  -b <len>, --bufferlen <len>
    Sets internal capture buffer length. Valid range <4096,134217728>.
  -A, --capture-from-all-devices
    Captures data from all devices connected to selected Root Hub.
  --devices <list>
    Captures data only from devices with addresses present in list.
    List is comma separated list of values. Example --devices 1,2,3.
  --inject-descriptors
    Inject already connected devices descriptors into capture data.
  -I,  --init-non-standard-hwids
    Initializes NonStandardHWIDs registry key used by USBPcapDriver.
    This registry key is needed for USB 3.0 capture.
```

Comment: my computer does not connect the bluetooth adapter as USB

Comment: Which computer would you like to use?

Comment: my own actually. I saw that is sniff all USB device, but i need only Bluetooth. And I dont understand how can I run it from python script for 15 second and get output in pcap